# Anaconda default directory

Tags: python, directory, anaconda

```
pd.read_csv('C:\Users\aaa\Desktop\contrylist.csv')
```

plz help guys.I am a beginner in pandas..i am not able to open this csv files.
Also I want to ask which is default directory for anacondas where I can store files and open them in below format

```
pd.read_csv('contrylist.csv')
```

Comment: What OS are you using? In windows its with \ (and you should double the backlashes to escape the characters \\) in linux/mac its with / (and you don't need to do anything else

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to put the full path, the file needs to be in the current directory, which you can see from

```
import os
os.path.abspath(os.path.curdir)
```

To change the current directory, use `os.chdir`

```
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\aaa\Desktop')
```

By the way, if you use IPython, then you can just use `%pwd` to see the current directory and `%cd` to change it.

Answer (score 3):

Double your backslashes.

```
pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\aaa\\Desktop\\contrylist.csv')
```

Or use raw strings:

```
pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\aaa\Desktop\contrylist.csv')
```

Backslash is a special character in string literals and it's used for escaping. You should read the docs: [strings](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) and [string literals](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals).